# Variable in Vue.js is not reactive

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Why is my `grid` variable not reactive? In the `toggle(index)` method, after
the logic, the `console.log(this.grid)` is printing the correct output but the `grid` variable isn't updating

```js
<template>
  <div class="game-container">
  
    <div>{{ grid }}</div>

    <div class="board">
      <div 
        @click="toggle(index)" 
        ref="squares" 
        v-for="(item, index) in grid" 
        :key="index" 
        class="square" 
        :class="{ 'on': item }">
        {{ item }} {{ index }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'GameComponent',
  data() {
    return {
      size: 5,
      grid: Array(25).fill(true),
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle(index) {
      const C = index
      const N = index - this.size >= 0 ? index - this.size : null
      const E = (index + 1) % this.size != 0 ? index + 1 : null
      const S = index + this.size < this.size * this.size ? index + this.size : null
      const W = index % this.size != 0 ? index - 1 : null

      this.grid[C] = !this.grid[C]
      if (N) this.grid[N] = !this.grid[N]
      if (E) this.grid[E] = !this.grid[E]
      if (S) this.grid[S] = !this.grid[S]
      if (W) this.grid[W] = !this.grid[W]

      console.log(this.grid)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

.game-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.board {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 40rem;
}

.square {
  width: 8rem;
  height: 8rem;
  border: 2px solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.on {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.hover {
  background-color: orange;
}
</style>
```

Comment: toggling the array elements will not make `this.grid` reactive. You have to assign the whole `this.grid` on toggle to make it reactive. You can use `this.grid.$set(index, val)` or you can also use this `let tempArray[]; tempArray = this.grid; tempArray[targetPosition]  = value; this.grid = tempArray;`

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in Vue are not reactive by design. It is well documented https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays, with solutions.

But who reads manuals these days, right?)